# Reading data conditionally

Tags: python

My text data file looks like this. I want to read this data conditionally and store in a list such that if right hand side equals one, I want the line to be added in the list.

```
 [ 1, 5, 2] = -0.0
 [ 1, 5, 3] = -0.0
 [ 1, 5, 4] = -0.0
 [ 1, 5, 6] = -0.0
 [ 1, 5, 7] = 1.0
 [ 1, 5, 8] = -0.0
 [ 2,10] = 0.0
 [ 2,11] = 1.0
 [ 3, 2] = 1.0
 [ 3, 4] = -0.0
 [ 3, 5] = -0.0
 [ 3, 6] = -0.0
 [ 3, 7] = -0.0
```

I tried using the following code but it wont work. Please guide me towards the right direction.

```
with open("t.txt", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        col=line.split()
        if col[-1]!= '-0.0' or col[-1]!= '0.0':
            array.append(col)
```

EDIT: I changed the code to:

```
with open("t.txt", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        col=line.split()
        if col[-1]!= '-0.0': 
            if col[-1]!= '0.0':
                array.append(col)
```

Now the result I am getting is:

```
[['y:', '3', 'dimensions,', '657', 'entries:'],
 ['[', '1,', '5,', '7]', '=', '1.0'],
 ['[', '2,', '9,11]', '=', '1.0'],
 ['[', '3,', '6,', '2]', '=', '0.9999999999999876'],
 ['[', '6,', '8,', '3]', '=', '-1.2545520178264269e-14'],
 ['[', '7,', '4,', '3]', '=', '1.0'],
 ['[10,', '9,11]', '=', '-0.0x:', '2', 'dimensions,', '91', 'entries:'],
 ['[', '1,', '8]', '=', '1.0'],
 ['[', '2,11]', '=', '1.0'],
 ['[', '3,', '2]', '=', '1.0'],
 ['[', '7,', '3]', '=', '1.0'],
 ['[', '8,10]', '=', '1.0'],
 ['[10,', '7]', '=', '1.0']]
```

Looking for a cleaner output.

Comment: `array = [line for line in ins if lines.rstrip().endswith('1.0')]` should do it.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens? However, your condition you wrote in words sounds more like `if int(col[-1]) == 1:`

Comment: I have more than two conditions on the R.H.S, the reason I went with unequal sign.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues in your code:

By default `.split()` uses space as its delimitor, to split each line into left and right you need to pass `=`.

You have a logic error in your condition, `or` allows everything in because nothing can be `'-0.0'` and `'0.0'` at the same time. Switch it to an `and` to make it functional, or to make it better in reality it should be testing that `col[-1]` equals `1.0`:

`if col[-1] == '1.0':`

In order for your input to be compared correctly you should strip whitespace out, you can use a list comprehension for this:

`col = [n.strip() for n in line.split('=')]`

`col` will still be left with whitespace if you striped the line as a whole.

Hopefully that will get you back on the right track.